# Add To Cart redux react problem, cant get the 'CART_ADD_ITEM' constants in my redux devtools and the console show me error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

so i'm working on a e-shop, and im facing an issue that my CART_ADD_ITEM constant seems to be invisible to my code so i have an Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404 and CART_ADD_ITEM don't appear in my redux dev tools ....

Here is my code

cartConstants :

`export const CART_ADD_ITEM = 'CART_ADD_ITEM';`

cartActions :

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from "../constants/cartConstants";

export const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`api/products/${productId}`);
    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload:{
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            product: data._id,
            qty,
        },
    });
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

cartReducers

```
export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload;
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);
            if(existItem){
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) => 
                        x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
                    ),
                };
            } else {
                return { ...state, cartItems : [...state.cartItems, item]};
            }
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

cartScreen

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';

export default function CartScreen(props) {
    const productId = props.match.params.id;
    const qty = props.location.search
    ? Number(props.location.search.split('=')[1])
    : 1;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        if(productId){
            dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
        }
    }, [dispatch, productId, qty]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Cart Screen</h1>
            <p>ADD TO CART : ProductID: {productId} Qty : {qty} </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

store.js

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore, compose, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';
import { productDetailsReducer, productListReducer } from './reducers/productReducers';

const initialState = {
    cart:{
        cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
        : [],
    }, 
};
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
});
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

and the button on product page for add to cart :

```
<button onClick={addToCartHandler} className="primary block">Add To Cart</button>
```

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Request failed with status code 404

You are getting a 404 Not Found error which means that your URL path is wrong, so obviously you'll want to change that.  You probably meant to write `/api/products/${productId}` with a `/` at the beginning.

#### Uncaught (in promise) Error

`Axios.get` is a `Promise`.  Sometimes the request succeeds and other times it fails.  You code is not properly handling the cases where it fails.  The word "Uncaught" in that error message means that you need to "catch" the error.  You do that with a `try`/`catch` block and dispatch some sort of error action when it fails. (Or you could catch and do nothing)

```
export const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`api/products/${productId}`);
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: {
        name: data.name,
        image: data.image,
        price: data.price,
        countInStock: data.countInStock,
        product: data._id,
        qty
      }
    });
    // I don't think this is the best place for setting localStorage
    localStorage.setItem( "cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems) );
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM_FAILURE,
      payload: error
    });
  }
};
```

The easier thing to do is to use the [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) helper function from redux-toolkit.  You just have to write the async part of your code and it will automatically dispatch different actions for pending, fulfilled, and rejected.

```
export const addToCart = createAsyncThunk(
  'cart/addItem', // base action name
  async ({productId, qty}) => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`api/products/${productId}`);
    // return the success payload
    return {
        name: data.name,
        image: data.image,
        price: data.price,
        countInStock: data.countInStock,
        product: data._id,
        qty
      }
    }
);
```

You would need to change your action names.  You would also need to change the calls to your action creator to pass both arguments as properties of an object.

```
dispatch(addToCart({productId, qty}))
```